# Use a single push button in two different circuits with different voltages

Tags: current, switches, audio, controller

I recently assembled a multiple switch formed by some resistors and 3 push buttons (NO) to drive an audio effect for guitar (which I will call effect 1), this switch is passive and receives current (about 6.25 volts) while sends the signal from a stereo jack cable. The switch works correctly as hoped

If I plug the same homemade switch to another audio effect (which I'll call effect 2), the current it receives is about 3.3 volts and again no problem, everything works great.

What I would like to do is duplicate the stereo signal to drive the two effects simultaneously, so  add another stereo cable to drive both effect 1 and effect 2 with the same multiple switch.. what components should I use to be able to close the circuit on both effects without mixing the different currents?

[image]

Comment: How about dual push buttons (the equivalent of a SPDT relay)? You could operate the two circuits electrically independent from a single push button.

Comment: Hi @winny thank you for your comment, do you mean a double switch that can close the two circuits separately with a single click? I currently have 3 momentary footswitches mounted in the box

Comment: Yes. If it’s an option to replace them, you can greatly simplify your problem. If not, it will be a question if your two devices share ground or not. You could still cheat with a relay.

Comment: so, something like this? [link](https://guitarpedalparts.com/products/momentary-dpdt-foot-switch) But in this case I can't use the switch to close the 2 circuits simultaneously right?

Comment: Do you have one (mono) signal input or two (stereo)? If mono and you want momentary and not latching, then you can use the switch in the link.

Comment: no, I've 2 stereo signals

Comment: Ouch. Consider a simple push button and cheat your way to as many signals as you need with relays.

Comment: Could you please suggest me a relay to manage 6,5 and 3.3 volts?

Comment: But wait, one stereo signal input only? That’s just a 4pst or 4pdt push button. Rare, but exists.

Comment: No, I've two stereo signals to manage at same time with 3 momentary switch

Comment: Please draw a block diagram of it with every signal represented. If 9 V operated, pretty much any of these relays would work: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/signal-relays-up-to-2-amps/189?s=N4IgjCBcoOwExVAYygFwE4FcCmAaEA9lANogDMADAKxUAcC%2BctYZMALCIwGwxfWcg4bAJzC4DQSLpcBbKjFq8BcCop7Km9YQJgUKYWjPxdDVMB2OmWyipX74WtthJZVbCALr4ADqiggAZQwASwA7AHMQAF8oxhJA4PDQgEMAGwACdGxU5IBPEA8ooA